# R process xml file with readLines

Tags: r

What is happening when I read any flat file (.abc is just dummy extension) with Readlines, What kind of structure, I can't see anything with str!!
I don't see any columns and can not assign any
this is example of my file. I never heard about this in R. I tried to find string in this file and realized that I can not refer to any of its column??

```
sink("x1.abc")
cat("(google.j.qbp==1);(function()")
cat("\n")
cat("google.timers[a].e[b]=c};google.bit=star/Alpha")
cat("\n")
cat("(m.getAttribute(\"role\"")
cat("\n")
sink()

file.show("x1.abc")

data <- readLines("x1.abc")
 str(data)
> chr [1:3] "(google.j.qbp==1);(function()" "google.timers[a].e[b]=c};google.bit=star/Alpha" "(m.getAttribute(\"role\""
colnames(data)
colnames(data) < "col1"
> logical(0)     ###??????????
```

Answer (score 1):

`readLines()` returns a character vector, it has no dimension attribute, no rows, and no columns. From `help(readLines)` -

> **Value**
>
> A character vector of length the number of lines read.

Your `str(data)` call confirms that you have a length three character vector.

Anyway, here's what I think you want. You could try `read.table()`, setting the column name in the same line.

```
read.table("x1.abc", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names = "col1")
#                                             col1
# 1                  (google.j.qbp==1);(function()
# 2 google.timers[a].e[b]=c};google.bit=star/Alpha
# 3                         (m.getAttribute("role"
```

Comment: The OP forgot a `-` so was actually asking R if it was less than `col1`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr - Ahh, I see.  Thanks for clarifying.